# How to download local file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, dart-null-safety

I'm making my portfolio website on flutter i want that if someone click on download cv button,it download on his device.CV is place in the assets folder.

```
downloadFile(url) {
    AnchorElement anchorElement =
        AnchorElement(href: url);
    anchorElement.download = "CV";
    anchorElement.click();
  }

TextButton(
                    onPressed: () =>
                        downloadFile("/assets/files/Hassan_Naveed_CV.pdf"),
                    child: FittedBox(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Download CV",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Theme.of(context)
                                    .textTheme
                                    .bodyText1!
                                    .color),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: defaultPadding / 2,
                          ),
                          const Icon(Icons.download, color: Color(0xFF8B8B8D))
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
```

[image]

[image: when i click on the download button ,it shows download failed]

when i click on the download button ,it shows download failed

Answer (score 2):

Try checking the path of your file against where you call it and whether you have given access to that 'files' folder in your pubspec.yml. Your code looks good to me, I think it comes from the given path.
Also check that there are no spaces or unwanted characters in the file name.

Comment: Path and every thing in pubspec.yml is ok , if you knew another method for web please tell me

Comment: second thing when i try to download image from the same method it download fine don't know why it did'nt download the pdf file